# Template blocks not appearing in extended templates in Django App

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm going through the Tango with Django book and came across an error I can't seem to fix. In my Django web app, in the templates that extend base.html, my title block and side bar block aren't rendering but my body block is. I can't seem to figure out what the problems. Is there something more I need to implement blocks in my project?

here is my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load mango_template_tags %} 

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Mango -
            {% block title_block %}
                How to Tango with Django
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            {% block sidebar_block %}
                {% get_category_list category %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

        <div>
            {% block body_block %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <ul>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'restricted' %}">Restricted Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'add_category' %}">Add New Category</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Index</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is one of the templates that extends base.html, about.html

```
{% extends 'rango/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title_block %}
    About
{% endblock %}


{% block body_block %}
    <div>
        <h1 class="page-header">About Page</h1>         
        This tutorial has been put together by: leifos and maxwelld90 
    </div>  
    <div> 
        <img src="{% static "images/flower.jpg " %}"
        alt = "picture of flower" 
        width=300 height = 300/> <br />
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}city.jpg"
        alt = "picture of city" 
        width=300 height = 300/>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and in case its needed heres the urls.py for the app and project

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from mango import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.show_category, name='show_category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_page/$', views.add_page, name='add_page'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^restricted/', views.restricted, name="restricted"),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
]

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from mango import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^mango/', include('mango.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If any more files are needed I'll edit them to my question. Thanks for any help.

about view

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from mango.models import Category
from mango.models import Page

from mango.forms import CategoryForm, PageForm
from mango.forms import UserForm, UserProfileForm

def about(request):
    context_dict = {'description': "It has random functionalities",
                    'author': "Billy Bob"}
    return render(request, 'mango/about.html', context=context_dict)
```

Comment: What does the about view look like?

Comment: added about view to end of question